# What are the differences between the "comparative" and "cross-mythology" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking through the tags and considering some edits (not yet suggested), when I noticed that two tags, [cross-mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-mythology) and [comparative](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative), looked very similar.

They both seem to be about elements that exist in more than one religion, though [cross-mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-mythology) seems to be more focused on elements that are *shared* between religions.

Do these tags share the same purpose, or are they different? If the latter, then how are they different?

Comment: I mean, the site has only been around for a few days. Probably someone created one of the tags, and then someone created the other tag without noticing that the former existed. [I proposed they be synonymized](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/a/70/), which ought to happen after we get pro tempore moderators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know I created [cross-mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-mythology) with one of my first questions; one week later, I now think [comparative](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative) is a better tag.

Also, all questions here are about Mythology, there is no reason to have an extremely long tag name just to include the word `mythology`. For these reasons, I support @senshin's [synonym-request](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/70/) and think we should use [comparative](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative) as the target.

---

The tags have been merged.